# Power Query Business Hours Between Two Dates/Times in Total Minutes

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to write a  M query to calculate between business hours 8:00 - 17:00 M-F for order submissions. I'm having an issue for when orders enter Service Review on the weekend or Friday and submitted on Monday.

For example:
If an order is in service review on Monday 1/2/203 8:00am and is submitted on Tuesday 1/3/2023 12:00 pm then the total minutes = 720 minutes. This works with the code currently.

If an order is in service review on Friday 1/6/2023 5:00 pm,  and is submitted on the next Monday  1/9/23 at 8:10 am, the total minutes = 10 minutes.

If an order is service review on Saturday 1/7/2023  or Sunday 1/8/2023 anytime and submitted on Saturday 1/7/2023 or Sunday 1/7/2023 then the minutes = 0 minutes

```
NonWorkingTime = List.Transform(List.Numbers(0,15*60), each #time(17,0,0)+#duration(0,0,_,0)),
SRReal = Table.AddColumn(SR, "Min in SRRR", each [a=Date.DayOfWeekName( Date.From([Service Review Date])),
b = [Submitted Date]-[Service Review Date],
c = if a = "Saturday" then b - #duration(2,0,0,0) else if a = "Sunday" then b - #duration(1,0,0,0) else b,
d= List.Count( List.Difference(  List.Transform(List.DateTimes([Service Review Date], Duration.TotalMinutes(c), #duration(0,0,1,0)), each Time.From(_)), NonWorkingTime))][d]),
```

Changing `c = if a = "Friday" then b - #duration(2,0,0,0)  else b,
gives:

| Service Review Date | Submitted Date | Min in SR | Expected | Start Day | End Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 8:00:00 AM | 2/1/2023 12:00:00 PM | 43980 | M-F 8-5 | Sunday | Wednesday |
| 1/1/2023 4:50:00 PM | 1/2/2023 8:10:00 AM | 20 | 10 | Sunday | Monday |
| 1/5/2023 8:00:00 AM | 1/8/2023 8:10:00 AM | 3430 | Thu + Fri | Thursday | Sunday |
| 1/5/2023 4:52:00 PM | 1/6/2023 8:10:00 AM | 18 | 18 | Thursday | Friday |
| 1/5/2023 4:55:00 PM | 1/5/2023 4:58:00 PM | 3 | 3 | Thursday | Thursday |
| 1/6/2023 8:10:00 AM | 1/8/2023 8:30:00 AM | 20 | 470 (Friday ins) | Friday | Sunday |
| 1/6/2023 8:10:00 AM | 1/6/2023 8:30:00 AM |  | 20 | Friday | Friday |
| 1/7/2023 4:50:00 PM | 1/9/2023 8:10:00 AM | 1460 | 10 | Saturday | Monday |
| 1/7/2023 4:55:00 PM | 1/7/2023 5:15:00 PM | 5 | 0 | Saturday | Saturday |
| 1/7/2023 4:56:00 PM | 1/8/2023 8:10:00 AM | 14 | 0 | Saturday | Sunday |
| 1/8/2023 8:00:00 AM | 1/9/2023 8:10:00 AM | 550 | 10 | Sunday | Monday |
| 1/8/2023 12:00:00 PM | 1/8/2023 12:30:00 PM | 30 | 0 | Sunday | Sunday |

Comment: Please add sample data as copiable text and expected output. Please also check the logic of what you have written as your numbers aren't adding up. I also don't think your existing code works if the time spans over multiple weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duration for just 8:00-17:00 M-F

[image]

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Service Review Date", type datetime}, {"Submitted Date", type datetime}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom1", each List.DateTimes([Service Review Date], Duration.TotalMinutes([Submitted Date]-[Service Review Date]), #duration(0, 0, 1, 0))),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Minutes", each List.Sum(List.Transform([Custom1], each 
    if Date.DayOfWeekName(_) = "Saturday"
    or Date.DayOfWeekName(_) = "Sunday"
    or Time.Hour(_)<8
    or Time.Hour(_)>16 then 0  else 1))),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Custom1"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```